# eval-after-load and define-key of raise-sexp results in an error of "Unbalanced parenthesis"

Tags: debugging

```
(eval-after-load 'lisp-mode
  (define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "C-c r") 'raise-sexp))
```

When above lisp is evaluated, it shows following error message.

```
up-list: Scan error: "Unbalanced parentheses", 183, 1
```

---

What's strange to me is that following lisp is evaluated without any error:

```
(eval-after-load 'lisp-mode
  (define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "C-c r") 'forward-sexp))
```

Could someone help me figure out what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(with-eval-after-load 'lisp-mode
  (define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "C-c r") 'raise-sexp))
```

Alternatively - note the **quote** mark before the argument:

```
(eval-after-load 'lisp-mode
  '(define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "C-c r") 'raise-sexp))
```

`eval-after-load` is a function, which means that it evaluates all of its arguments. So you want to quote the form you pass to it, so it is evaluated after loading, not when `eval-after-load` itself is evaluated.

`with-eval-after-load` is a macro, which means that it does not necessarily evaluate any of its arguments (and a macro often doesn't evaluate any of them). Emacs added `with-eval-after-load` specifically because with `eval-after-load` some users have fallen into the same gotcha that you did: forgetting a quote mark or not realizing that they wanted one.

Comment: `eval-after-load` is a function so you should quote the form you pass to it; `with-eval-after-load` is a macro.

Comment: if its required, then why the code for forward-sexp worked fine,  now interested

Comment: Because it's actually the same as doing `(progn (define-key emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "C-c r") 'forward-sexp) (eval-after-load 'lisp-mode 'forward-sexp))`, i.e. it performs the binding *before* loading `lisp-mode` and actually *runs* `forward-sexp` after `lisp-mode` is loaded (which is apparently harmless, but running `raise-sexp` causes problems).

Comment: @npostavs Now I get it. What I evaluated in the question resulted in keybinding and executing the command itself, then.